# Using fontawesome icons in dash-leaflet webapp

Tags: python, font-awesome, folium, dash-leaflet

i'm using an dash-leaftlet app with a real-time map. The markers are updated every 30 secondes, that works. Now i would like to change the icon and use the fontawesome icons. That doesn't work, i tried reading the documentation but nothing works. Before that i was using folium in the same matter, i was able to make the marker with a fontawesome icon, but in dash-leaflet that seems really to complicated.

i'm aiming for something like this :

[image]

Here is my current code, that does show the fontawesome icon, but not like to image above. In the end, i'm aiming for something like in the image above, and be able to change the color of the marker/icon.

```
[...]

external_scripts = [
    {
        'src':'https://kit.fontawesome.com/6f4324546a.js',
        'crossorigin':'anonymous'
    }
]

app = Dash(__name__,
           external_scripts=external_scripts)
```

[...]

```
# Define two different icon options
green_icon = dict(
    html='<i class="fa-solid fa-kiwi-bird" style="color: green;"></i>',
    className='myDivIcon',
    iconSize=[40, 40]
)

red_icon = dict(
    html='<i class="fa-solid fa-kiwi-bird" style="color: red;"></i>',
    className='myDivIcon',
    iconSize=[40, 40]
)

def choose_icon(condition):
    return green_icon if condition else red_icon
```

[...]

```
    markers_data = []
    for bird in bird_map_devices:
        if bird['gps'] != 'False':
            markers_data.append(
                dl.DivMarker(
                    position=(bird['gps']['Location']['Latitude'], bird['gps']['Location']['Longitude']),
                    children=[
                        dl.Tooltip(bird['name'])
                    ],
                    iconOptions=choose_icon(True)
                    #icon=dl.Icon(color='red'),
                )
            )
    
    return [dl.TileLayer()] + markers_data
```

everything is mention.

Comment: I didn't check but usually font need to use `@font-face` with url to font file `ttf`. And it needs to assign `font`  in `CSS`

Comment: maybe you should check `JavaScript Console` in `DevTools` in `Chrome` or `Firefox` - to see if there are some errors.

Comment: maybe it still needs to add `fontawesome.css` to work correctly